# Cannot import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO in side webapps

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am using beaglebone black revC for my capstone project. I want to control the gpio from a smartphone. I've written lock.py to control the GPIO, and I import lock in views.py.

In file lock.py I import Adafruit_BBIO :

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
```

In file views.py :

```
import lock
```

Both files - lock.py and views.py are in /webapps/bbb/app/ 
I run with the command:

```
/opt/py27/bin/uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --chdir /webapps/bbb --module run:app &
```

When I run the command I get the following error :

[image]

How can I import Adafaruit_BBIO.GPIO in this case?

Comment: Have you [installed it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Adafruit_BBIO/0.0.19)?

Comment: ofcourse I have installed it, i can run python file have import it ok by command python2 somefile.py

Comment: Can you run `python lock.py`?

Comment: yes I can, I use python2.7